# Python request response parsing incorrectly

Tags: python, json

I am writing out a code snippet to insert the wind speed and direction in to a larger script used to update an e-ink display. I was working on this last night and it was working, then I made a change, it stopped working and I can't for the life of me figure out what I did as I didn't save my older versions...

This is what I have right now:

```
import json
import requests

WEATHER_API = 'abcd1234'

def degreesToTextDesc(deg):
    if deg > 337.5: return "N"
    if deg > 292.5: return "NW"
    if deg > 247.5: return "W"
    if deg > 202.5: return "SW"
    if deg > 157.5: return "S"
    if deg > 122.5: return "SE"
    if deg >  67.5: return "E"
    if deg >  22.5: return "NE"
    return "N"


try:
    weather_response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", params={"appid":WEATHER_API, "units":'imperial', "zip":'40217,us'}).json()
    forecast_response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast", params={"appid":WEATHER_API, "units":'imperial', "zip":'40217,us'}).json()
    current_wind_speed = str(int(weather_response['wind']['speed']))
    current_wind_dir = str(degreesToTextDesc(weather_response['wind']['deg']))
    forecast_wind_speed = str(int(forecast_response['wind']['speed']))
    forecast_wind_dir = str(degreesToTextDesc(forecast_response['wind']['deg']))
    print(current_wind_speed + ' / ' + current_wind_dir)
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

And for output I am just getting 'wind' where before, I had gotten to the point of it outputting "13 / NW" (for example).

The change came when I tried to add the forecast wind changing the successful print line to:
`print(current_wind_speed + ' / ' + current_wind_dir + ' -> ' + forecast_wind_speed + ' / ' + forecast_wind_dir)`

The output from forecast_response and weather_response is as below:

```
{'cod': '200', 'message': 0, 'cnt': 40, 'list': [{'dt': 1702101600, 'main': {'temp': 58.42, 'feels_like': 56.84, 'temp_min': 56.82, 'temp_max': 58.42, 'pressure': 1014, 'sea_level': 1014, 'grnd_level': 996, 'humidity': 61, 'temp_kf': 0.89}, 'weather': [{'id': 804, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'overcast clouds', 'icon': '04n'}], 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'wind': {'speed': 12.1, 'deg': 185, 'gust': 33.93}, 'visibility': 10000, 'pop': 0, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2023-12-09 06:00:00'},
```

```
{'coord': {'lon': -85.7404, 'lat': 38.2174}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 61.93, 'feels_like': 61.77, 'temp_min': 59.81, 'temp_max': 63.01, 'pressure': 1011, 'humidity': 84}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 13.8, 'deg': 190, 'gust': 21.85}, 'rain': {'1h': 0.43}, 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'dt': 1702148181, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2000057, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1702126073, 'sunset': 1702160571}, 'timezone': -18000, 'id': 0, 'name': 'Louisville', 'cod': 200}
```

I think I've fiddled with it too much at this point and need a second set of eyes. I'm sure it's a silly mistake I just can't see the forest for the trees. I also know it would be better to use OWMs API instead of requests, but their documentation is a bit confusing with all the different subscriptions.

Comment: Is this the EXACT code you are running? Or did you maybe fiddle around with WEATHER_API too? Reason being, if you remove the try/except you can see you aren't getting a valid response ("Invalid API key etc..."). With the except block it's just printing out the key it couldn't find in the junk response.

Comment: It appears to work fine, what's the error?

Comment: @Error_2646 I removed my API Key... you would need a valid API key from OWM to test. It works to pull the entire JSON response, it's parsing the wind speed and degrees that isn't working.

Comment: @Reilas not sure what you mean? The error is that the print output is 'wind' which is not what it should be. It should be the string of wind speed / wind direction.

Comment: @pslaugh, it printed, _"13 / S"_ here.

Comment: @plsaugh Yes, figured so. Was wondering if you might have changed it to dummy text and forgotten.

Comment: @plsaugh And is that the exact output you are getting for forecast_response? I don't see a closing bracket for the 'list' key.

Comment: @Error_2646 no, it is a huge block it goes out to 5 days at 3 hour intervals and didn't want to copy all that here lol. It just repeats the 'dt' section for each interval.

Comment: @Reilas Okay! I knew I wasn't going crazy! I just cannot figure out why it isn't printing that for me anymore... I even created a new file, copied the code as above (plus my API key) and ran it and again got 'wind'

Comment: @plsuagh Odd, is it at least representative of the first N characters? I don't see how forecast_response['wind'] could be a valid key, since in this truncated output 'wind' would still be in "lists"'s value, assuming the closing bracket comes later on.

Comment: @Error_2646 at the moment I'm just trying to get the current_wind parts to work, but I do see what you mean, I think I was just changing out current to forecast but the output organization is different, so  forecast_response['list']['wind']['speed'] and forecast_response['list']['wind']['deg']. Still doesn't explain the 'wind' output of (current_wind_speed + ' / ' + current_wind_dir)...

Comment: @pslaugh Try commenting out everything that has to do with the forecast response and see if weather_response is still working. Even if you are only printing (current_wind_speed + ' / ' + current_wind_dir) it's still trying to get that bad key from forecast_response in the try block.

Comment: @pslaugh And just for preemptive sanity. forecast_response['list']['wind']['speed'] is unlikely to work. Because the value of 'list' is a list, not a dictionary that you can access via key. Example - print({'cod':1,'list':[{'wind':2}]}['list']['wind'])

Comment: @pslaugh, as a recommendation, if you know the _API_ resolve works correctly, try testing your code with a static response text; as opposed to querying every time.

Comment: @pslaugh, additionally, a _[16-wind compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass)_ is typically used in wind direction applications.  Let me know if you need any additional help!

Comment: @Error_2646 that was it! Adding the forecast_response wind lines are what broke it. I really appreciate that sanity check. I'll take yours and Reilas' recommendations into consideration and keep working on that portion of it. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Changed the string to forecast_response['list'][0]['wind']['speed'] and forecast_response['list'][0]['wind']['deg'] which is now working and I have an output with current and forecast wind! @Reilas, I appreciate the note on the 16-points, but I am planning on the 8 points being mapped to icons I have in my library to display on the screen, and I don't need that sort of precision. Thanks again both of you!